# React.js NavLink full url after build

Tags: reactjs, url, href

I am using React with Redux to develop my app.
By default:

```
<NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
```

will generate

```
<a href="/about">About</a>
```

Is there a way to generate the full url after build, something like that:

```
<a href="https://some-domain.com/about">About</a>
```

Thanks is advance!

Comment: Why not just use an `a` tag? React router links are meant to operate within the website's path.

Comment: React router will generate relative paths to your application. If you need a full path why don't you just use the <a> tag you just mentioned in your question? Is there a specific reason you want it with ReactRouter?

Comment: @TravisM I can't use a tag, this is a SPA, the page will reload if a tag is used

Comment: What is the purpose of having the full url then if not to link somewhere else? The default behavior will work fine if you are just navigating relatively

Comment: Exactly, that is the reason ReactRouter won’t show the full path. Because it will load that URL. May I ask why you want the full URL? Maybe that will help understand the problem.

Comment: @Kapil the reason is SEO, it seems full url in href's are very important

Comment: Are you using creat-react-app or static site for your SPA?  Because if you want good SEO I would recommend using server side rendering. A static site will not provide you with maximum SEO options. I do not have much exp with this area but as far as I know you do not want a static site if you want SEO. There are frameworks like Next.js that provide good SSR, maybe research about them, it should provide a solution to your problem.

Comment: As I already said, SSR is your best option if you want good SEO in a react app, other than that, I cannot recommend you anything else right now